# Настройка роутинга в Angular

Tags: typescript, angular, angular-routing

Настроил роутинг в app.module.ts

```
const appRoutes: Routes =[
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent},
  { path: 'house/:type/:series/:address', component: CalcComponent},
  { path: 'calc-custom', component: CalcCustomComponent},
  { path: 'payment', component: PaymentComponent},
  { path: 'order', component: OrderComponent},
  { path: 'modals', component: ModalsComponent},
  { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }
];
```

При переходе по ссылке [http://localhost:4000/house/panel/p-44t-ug/?STREET=Покровская%20улица&HOUSE=14](http://localhost:4000/house/panel/p-44t-ug/?STREET=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0&HOUSE=14) перенаправляет на ссылку [http://localhost:4000/house/panel/p-44t-ug?STREET=Покровская%20улица&HOUSE=14](http://localhost:4000/house/panel/p-44t-ug?STREET=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0&HOUSE=14) и выдает шаблон 404 ошибки. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: `?STREET=...` это параметр запроса, а не параметр роута

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно обращаться вот как-то так http://localhost:4000/house/panel/p-44t-ug/HOUSE_ADDRESS

в соответствии с этим правилом 
{ path: 'house/:type/:series/:address', component: CalcComponent},

можно еще переписать правило, убрал адрес

{ path: 'house/:type/:series', component: CalcComponent},

и после уже анализировать GET параметр

Comment: что такое `Покровская%20улица%20HOUSE=14`? таким образом он не получит адрес, router не сможет это распарсить

Comment: часть его урла для примера. но вы правы, сейчас поправлю

Comment: К сожалению, мне нужно придерживаться именно формы: http://localhost:4000/house/panel/p-44t-ug/?STREET=Покровская%20улица&HOUSE=14
Так как страницы такого плана индексируются и мне нужно сохранить данные параметры запроса. Есть какая-то возможность?

Comment: дополнил ответ выше

Comment: Да,понял, спасибо большое!